How to call a procedure in pre-sql that uses function in another database as a parameter in informatica powercenter
Hello i have a question could it be possible to call a procedure in pre-sql that uses a function in another database as a parameter
here's the call in pre-sql
CALL P_Proc_Syntax('X', 'Y',1 ,10
,Fun_x('CUSTOMER'),Fun_y('CUSTOMER'));

note Fun_x and Fun_y are functions in another database that return sys_refcursor
i tried to use the function and procedure directly in the map but the problem is the return type is sys_refcursor and informatica cannot translate this datatype i think so the return of this function isn't exit in the transformation so i was forced to use it in pre-sql it works ok when all function are from the same database of the procedure so how can i do something like that in powercenter

Can you not create some link between two databases ? Like for Oracle, you can create DB link

You can use the PreSQL. It will execute the code on the DB server the session is connecting to. Now, it's up for the DB server to be able to execute the code, not Informatica anymore, so remove PowerCenter out of the picture and first make sure this code runs on your DB.
